# why my shader is black in the game mode?

Tags: unity, shaders

I used this useful [blending modes](http://www.elopezr.com/photoshop-blend-modes-in-unity/) It's good but it just work in Editor mode.
what is the problem?!

[image]

```
Shader "CodeCorsair/BlendModesFX" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}

        // This here gives hints to the shader to do pixel-time tricks
        _BlendMode("BlendMode", Range(0, 16)) = 0 // 0 is standard blend

        [HideInInspector] _BlendOp1("__op1", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _BlendSrc1("__src1", Float) = 1.0
        [HideInInspector] _BlendDst1("__dst1", Float) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _BlendSrcAlpha1("__src_alpha1", Float) = 1.0
        [HideInInspector] _BlendDstAlpha1("__dst_alpha1", Float) = 0.0
    }

    SubShader
    {       

    //  Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
    //ZWrite Off Lighting Off Cull Off Fog{ Mode Off }
    //LOD 110
        Pass
        {
            BlendOp[_BlendOp1]
            Blend[_BlendSrc1][_BlendDst1],[_BlendSrcAlpha1][_BlendDstAlpha1]

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _BlendMode;

            struct vin
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 color : COLOR;
            };

            v2f vert(vin v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
                o.color = v.color;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
            {   
                float4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                color.rgb = 1.0 - (1.0 / max(0.001, color.rgb * color.a + 1.0 - color.a)); // max to avoid infinity

                return color;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

when I used Transparent Queue I had this result:

[image]

Comment: This could be a difference in render order. Have you tried setting your material to draw in the Transparent or Overlay queues?

Comment: @DMGregory yes when I use Transparent queue It's like `alpha = 0` and disappear I will add result in my question.I don't know what is the problem It is strange! also my friend had this problem

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `uniform` keyword before the below lines:

```
sampler2D _MainTex;
float _BlendMode;
```

changes to:

```
uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
uniform float _BlendMode;
```

Comment: I tested this not work

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali remember, "it didn't work" is *never* enough information. Always include a description of the particular *way* it didn't work. "This had no visible effect" is different from "this caused my computer to catch fire" - even though both "don't work," the details of the symptoms can help us narrow down the problem.